# Moving from ADO to ADO.net

Tags: c#, database-design, orm, ado.net, ado

I am re-engineering a product which uses ADO communication for connecting to SQL.THe bussiness layer is in c++. The whole queries are written as SP's. 
I want the product to support SQL 2008 and may be Mysql(haven't finalized).

These are the changes i thought!

1. Moving the entire communication to ADO.net.
2. Since moving from SPs to ad-hoc SQL queries might require a lot of effort how about writing a wrapper C# layer which is used by the previous bussines layer which is in c++.
3. thought of seroiusly looking at some of the ORM tools. But since it involves lot of SP's i feel its better to go stage by stage.

I want feedbacks/suggetions for this. Is this a good trasnition?

Comment: Firstly, what sort of scale are we talking - is this 20? 200? SPs? Also: if your existing SPs work, why not just transition to SPs via ADO.NET? There's no need to jump to ad-hoc SQL here. The main thing I'll say, though: avoid the temptation of `DataTable` etc; nothing good comes from that :)

Comment: The present product uses SQL 2005. I would like to move it to SQL 2008 may be in the next version would like to support MySQL. I was also thinking on the similar lines . But will that C# wrapper around ado.net for bussiness layer which is in C++ will cause any performance hinderance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on personal preferences I would create LINQ2SQL or possibly Entity Framework layer to access the database. Both LINQ2SQL and Entity Framework can import definitions for and call stored procedures¹.

I would then gradually convert stored procedures to LINQ code.

¹) Within reasonable limits, SP:s with multiple return sets and selects that is not from a single table must be mapped manually, but it is still possible.

Comment: i have a question here. does Linq2SQL support MySQL? . I heard entity is good. But it will be a lot of re work for me. i think moving from ado to ado.net will give a better perfomance. isn't it ?

Comment: I think there is a third party MySQL provider for Linq2SQL, but then I would go for EF. Raw ADO.NET is a tad bit faster than using an OR mapper, but on the other hand writing code using an OR mapper is usually faster and less prone to bugs than using ADO.NET directly.

Comment: Whip up a small test project, import your database as an EF model and you'll see immediately if your SP:s are compatible with the EF designer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. i think i will do it in phase 2 and EF sounds good.. In phase 1 i am thinking of moving the communication to ADO.net and writing a wrapper in C# and using in bussiness layer which is in C++. Stored proc will remain the same, it will be called by C# code. If i do this way in phase 1(i understand that C++ will call C# using com interopability) will it cause any perfomance hinderance ?whats your opinion.

Comment: Oh ok .. i will write a test project !! but then if i have a SP doing a backup/archival(generally SP's working on lot of data) stuff is it better to keep it out of EF ?